# (experimenting with Javascript objects) Why is my function inside another function not working?

Tags: javascript, oop, polymorphism

I'm very new in terms of coding. I just want to know what I'm doing wrong here. When I try to execute car.drive(), the unlock() function doesn't operate even though it's inside the drive() function in the original code. I keep getting "unlock() is not defined".

```js
class Car extends drivable {
    constructor (color) {
        super(color);
    }
    
    drive() {
        super.drive();

        unlock(); {
            console.log("Car is unlocked");
        }
        
    }
    
const car = new Car("blue");

car.drive();
```

Comment: `unlock(); {` What exactly are you trying to do there? The syntax looks like you're trying to call a function named `unlock`, but you've defined no such function (and you're following it with a plain block `{ }`)

Comment: Pay attention to your code formatting. You forgot to close your class. Also, the unlock method should be inside the class itself and not inside drive method.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```js
class Car extends drivable {
    constructor (color) {
        super(color);
    }

    drive() {
        super.drive();        
        this.unlock();
    }

    unlock() {
        console.log("Car is unlocked");
    }
}

const car = new Car("blue");

car.drive();
```

Answer (score 2):

Take care about " ; ". How you wrote it means you just call the function, not define it.

```
unlock() {
    console.log("Car is unlocked");
}
```

EDIT: 
Sorry, I missed something:

```
class Car extends drivable {
    constructor(color) {
        super(color);
    }

    drive() {
        super.drive();
        this.unlock();
    }

    unlock() {
        console.log("Car is unlocked");
    }
}
```

Comment: You also missed `this.unlock()`  :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the function first before calling it.
But as you could simply call `console.log()` inside of the drive() function, that wouldnt make much sense here.

Anyway, could look like this:

```
drive() {
    super.drive();
    var unlock = function() {
        console.log("Car is unlocked");
    }
    unlock();
}
```

Or define and call the function at once like in the other answers